# Cannot flash phone to install TWRP (One plus One)

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, twrp, stock-rom

I have a one plus one phone and I am looking to install TWRP on it as its built in OS crashed. 
I have run

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

the result is

> > ... OKAY

command to unlock the phone but when I run

```
fastboot flash recovery c:\recovery.img
```

I get the error message that

> > writing 'recovery' Failed remote: Device not unlocked cannot flash or erase

I have gone over the docs but have not found anything helpful.
**Note:** Before the OS crashed I had not enabled USB debugging (Could this be the issue)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you rebooted the device after "Unlocking bootloader"?

> fastboot reboot

You need to execute this command before flashing custom ROM.
Also, You don't need to turn on USB debugging when unlocking bootloader.

Comment: +1 for no need to turn on USB debugging when unlocking bootloader

Comment: I did reboot the phone but the prob wasn' t solved.